# Power BI Report Builder : How to filter on a dataset column of commas separated values with a multivalue input parameter

Tags: filter, parameters, powerbi, multivalue

Is there a way to compare all the values in mutlivalue parameter to all comma separated values in a dataset column. This is a DAX Report Builder query from a Power BI desktop dataset so a SQL based answer is not going to be helpful. I can get multivalue parameters to work only if any value is listed first in the comma separated values in the column using  `iif(inStr(Join(Parameters!WORKDIST.Value,","),Fields!Vendor_Work_Districts_C.Value) > 0,"isWORKDIST","notWORKDIST"`

If my parameter values are 01,70 I will only get rows whose districts column values begins with 01,... or 70,...   If I have a districts column  with let's say 03,40,50,70,85, I would want that record because it has one of the parameter values.

Comment: Why do you have comma separated values in a dataset column?

Comment: Comma separated values in columns is common place here. I know I can change each value out for a row each in the desktop but I have three columns like this and I can substantially reduce the number of I/Os  can get this to work. Any tricks like with .Contains maybe?

Comment: Comma-separated values (or JSON, etc) may be common in your databases, but they shouldn't be common in your Power BI Datasets.  PQ can easily break them out into separate tables.  The transformation you are contemplating at runtime in DAX should be done at refresh time by Power Query (or SQL).  The _whole point_ of a Power BI Dataset is to present the data in a way that makes it quick and easy to create reports.